# How divide items (not just list) in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-relativelayout

[image]

On this picture have divided lines, but this just **drawble-line** where use `android:drawableTop="@drawable/border_line` and this bad solution. I need divided lines with ability to stretch. How can I do it, if my one item have not permanent state?

Please, help me find good solution.

P.S. block with number, date etc. is **CardView** and its gap not applicable in this situation.

Comment: Provide `xml` layout of your view As answer can be : you can simply change it to some kind of `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a vertical `LinearLayout` and set `android:divider="@drawable/border_line"`. This will automatically add the divider in between all items in the layout.